# Laravel TrustProxies can not get real ip for Throttle

Tags: laravel, nginx

I am running a project which combines both nodejs and php, and the part of nodejs is a SSR [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) (sth like [next](https://nextjs.org/)).

and requests for `/api/*` will be handled by php which constructed by [laravel](https://laravel.com/), requests for `/*` will be handled by nodejs which is running on `3000` port.

The key part of nginx configs is below:

```
    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

**How it works?**

1. When a client come to the website by typing in address bar, the request will be handled by nodejs first.
2. Then, nodejs will send a request to laravel for data.
3. Finally, the nodejs will send the html which had already been rendered with data from laravel to the client.

---

**So, here is the problem:**

I am using a Throttle in laravel, which means laravel needs the real ip.

Every time when a new user come to the website by typing in address bar, there is a request sent from nodejs, and the laravel will considered its ip is `127.0.0.1`, a `429 Too Many Requests` response will be got by nodejs even the real requests are sent from different ips.

---

**How I try to solve:**

I configed the `configs/trustedproxy.php`:

```php
<?php
return [
    'proxies' => '127.0.0.1',
    'headers' => Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL,
];
```

added `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;` in nginx config:

```
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    location /api/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

I am sure I registered the `TrustProxies::class` as middleware in `app\Http\Kernel.php`, also restarted nginx, but it still not work. Laravel still can't get the real ip.

I am using Laravel 8.12.

How can I solve it?
I googled it but nothing helped.

Thanks a lot! I am not good at English, sorry for grammatical errors.

Comment: Try trusting `*` instead of `127.0.0.1` for debugging purposes.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for your reply! I try this but errors still, I add a new middleware to log the `X-Forwarded-For` value like this `\Log::debug($request->header('X-Forwarded-For'));`, but only got `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I work out this bug.

Strictly speaking, it's not a proxy which you can't handle it as same as proxy exactly.

The nodejs will be considered as a client by Laravel, so some javascript have to be modified:

**When a client come to the website by typing in address bar, nodejs should get the real ip in server side(not the php nor client's browser), then make a request to laravel with that ip which will be added as `X-Forwarded-For`**

so, in a SSR Nuxt project:

`plugins/axios.js`

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export default ({ req }) => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
        ...
        if (process.server) {
            request.headers.common['X-Forwarded-For'] = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
        }
        return request;
    });
    ...
}
```